# Fine Uploader: how can I refer to a thumbnail with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, image, fine-uploader

My aim is to replace the just created thumbanail image with a background image on the parent div to let the image cover the squared div. I'm also using jQuery.
So I have to questions:

1. What's the event related to the thumbnail creation? I've tried with `onComplete` but I see the thumbnails has been generated before the upload is complete.
2. I'm working with `onComplete` at the moment (see above), how can I refer to the thumbnail img src just created? I've tried this script but of course it gets the first src of the thumbnails on the DOM: (function has been shortened)

```js
$('#fineuploader').fineUploader({
    callbacks: {
        onComplete: function(id) {
            imgbase64 = $('.qq-thumbnail-selector').attr('src');
            $('.qq-thumbnail-wrapper').css({
                'background-image':'url("' + imgbase64 + '")', 
                'background-position':'center center',
                'background-size':'cover'
            });
    }
});
```

Comment: Your code is missing a `}`

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan, this one is actually an edit of it I did for the post, the original code has all the '}'

Answer (score 0):

found a first solution myself to replace thumbnail img with a background image still on `onComplete` event, but what I really need is to apply this solution all of a sudden the thumbnails has been generated:

```
.on('complete', function (event, id, name, responseJSON) {
    if (responseJSON.success) {
            var fileid = $(this).fineUploader('getItemByFileId',id);
                var imgbase64 = $(fileid).find('.qq-thumbnail-selector').attr('src');
                $(fileid).find('.qq-thumbnail-wrapper').css({
                                                'background-image' : 'url("' + imgbase64 + '")',
                                                'background-position' : 'center center',
                                                'background-size' : 'cover'
                                            });
        };
    });
```